# Unresolved reference to symbol 'Media:1' in section 'Fragment:' and fragment element contains unexpected child element 'Product'

Tags: xml, wix, bootstrapper

I am new to installers. I am building something which has a prerequisite to my example. This code is throwing the two errors above.

1. This is NICE DCV as a prerequisite and Notepad (named as example).
2. I am using WIX installers and installing through command line. using Light and candle.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
   xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="rapy" UpgradeCode="12345678-1234-1234-1234-111111111111">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
    <Chain>
        <PackageGroupRef Id="NICEDCV" />
    </Chain>
   </Bundle>
   <Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id="NICEDCV">
        <MsiPackage
        Visible="yes"
      Cache="no"
      Compressed="no"
      ForcePerMachine="yes"
      Permanent="yes"
      Vital="yes"
      SourceFile=".\prerequisites\nice-dcv-client-Release-2021.0-7643.msi"  />
        <MsiPackage
      Visible="yes"
      Cache="no"
      Compressed="no"
      ForcePerMachine="yes"
      Permanent="yes"
      Vital="yes"
      SourceFile=".\prerequisites\nice-dcv-client-Release-2021.0-7643.msi" />
    </PackageGroup>
    <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="12345678-1234-1234-1234-111111111111" Name="Example Product Name" Version="0.0.1" Manufacturer="Example Company Name" Language="1033">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" Comments="Windows Installer Package" />
        <!--Media ='1' Cabinet='product.cab' EmbedCab='yes'/-->
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Example">
                    <Component Id="ApplicationFiles" Guid="12345678-1234-1234-1234-222222222222">
                        <File Id="ApplicationFile1" Source="example.exe" />
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
        <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationFiles" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>
    <!-- /PackageGroup -->
   </Fragment>
   </Wix>
```

Comment: It looks like you have mixed together a Bundle source file (used to make a **`setup.exe`**) and a regular WiX source file **`*.wxs`** (used to make an MSI file). If so, split them into their correct, separate files and put both projects in the same Visual Studio Solution. WiX quick start tips: `1)` [very long version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864), `2)` [short version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63308043/129130). [Click "WiX samples" here](https://installdude.com/jumpgate.php).